# Discord activity not working in sub command

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js, bots

Issue:
The bot's status is not changed when the subcommand is run. If a change status is run from `index.js`, it works fine.

Expected output:
Changes the bots status.

Command:

```
module.exports = {
    name: 'playing',
    description: 'playing status',
    guildOnly: true,
    args: true,
    devRole: true,
    usage: '<target>',
    execute(message, args) {
        message.channel.send(`Setting status to: ${args}`);
        client.user.setPresence({
            status: 'available',
            activity: {
                name: 'with ducks',
                type: 'PLAYING',
                url: 'https://discord.com'
            }
        });
    },
};
```

What calls the commands:

```
for (const file of commandFiles) {
    const command = require(`./commands/${file}`);
    client.commands.set(command.name, command);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't mention what the error is and I can't see where you define the `client` variable but it seems that's causing the error.

The `message` has a [`client`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=client) property that you can use to set its presence. So, instead of `client` use `message.client`:

```js
execute(message, args) {
  message.channel.send(`Setting status to: ${args}`);
  message.client.user.setPresence({
    status: 'available',
    activity: {
        name: 'with ducks',
        type: 'PLAYING',
        url: 'https://discord.com'
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: I was not getting any errors from it even with debug mode.